# Is it possible to insert arguments at different points in a command in linux while piping

Tags: linux, shell

For example, if I am piping say, '1\n2\n' to cal with options A and B like:

```
cat file-with-content.txt | xargs cal -A (1 here) -B (2 here).
```

Using the -I option just executes cal twice.

Comment: If there were four items in the pipe, would you want `cal -A 1 -B 2` and then `cal -A 3 -B 4`?

Comment: BTW, note `<file` instead of `cat file` in my answer. A pipeline forces the consumer to read front-to-back; a real file provides much more control: The tool receiving it can check the file's length (to set up a progress bar), or have different threads read from different places in the file to parallelize, or skip around in the file (to make things like `tail` efficient), etc. The use case here is one where `cat` is okay, since either `xargs` or a `while read` loop will be going front-to-back regardless, but using it unnecessarily is a bad habit to be in.

Comment: BTW, if your content is line-oriented, you may want to add the `-d $'\n'` argument to `xargs` (assuming it's the GNU version and has it available). Otherwise, xargs performs vaguely-shell-like (but not completely shell-compatible) word-splitting, so a line `two words` becomes two separate arguments rather than one argument with a space. If you need compatibility with BSD xargs (which doesn't support `-d`) while getting line-oriented behavior, the alternative to that is to put `tr '\n' '\0'` earlier in your pipeline and then use `xargs -0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) loop:

```
while IFS= read -r a && IFS= read -r b; do
  cal -A "$a" -B "$b"
done <file-with-content.txt
```

This does of course also work with a pipeline, though it's suboptimal to use them unnecessarily:

```
cat file-with-content.txt |
  while IFS= read -r a && IFS= read -r b; do
    cal -A "$a" -B "$b"
  done
```

---

The above assumes that there can be more than two items in your pipe, and you want to repeat as long as there are more items. This is in line with behavior of xargs, but if in your *real* case there are only ever two items, you can simplify:

```
# again, better to replace this with <file-with-content.txt
cat file-with-content |
  ( IFS= read -r a && IFS= read -r b && exec cal -A "$a" -B "$b" )
```

The `exec` consumes the subshell created by the parens to avoid paying a performance penalty for spinning it up.

Comment: Just read a bit more about `exec` ... very handy in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible to do this directly with xargs but you can bypass this with a call to `sh`:

```
$ seq 1 10 | xargs -n2 sh -c 'echo arg1 "$1" arg2 "$2"' -
arg1 1 arg2 2
arg1 3 arg2 4
arg1 5 arg2 6
arg1 7 arg2 8
arg1 9 arg2 10
```

So in case of the OP, this would become:

```
$ cat -- file-with-content.txt | xargs -n2 sh -c 'cal -A "$1" -B "$2"' -
```