# Passing two arguments to another command in the same line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface

I need to pass two arguments to the same command. The output of the first command look like this:

```
BLA    BLE
A1     B2
A2     B3
```

Right now I using this for using the first argument

```bash
firstCommand | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I_ secondCommand _
```

But the secondCommand has changed and right now I need to pass a second argument

```
secondComman A --second B
```

Is this posssible using xargs?

I try multiple stackoverflow solution, but none with was succesful.

Comment: Funny thing, we had a very similar question just a few days ago. See [Is it possible to insert arguments at different points in a command in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75412628)

Comment: please update the question with some of the *multiple stackoverflow solutions* that were unsuccessful

Comment: (As markp-fuso says: When you just say things didn't work, we don't know why or how they didn't work, so we don't know how to avoid sending you in a direction that has the same problem, and we can't judge an answer's correctness based on whether it'll fail the same way given the details of your usage mode or input data; if you want to disambiguate from an existing question, _show exactly how that question's answers fail when you try them_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add printing 2nd argument to `awk` and capture 2 arguments with `xargs`:

```
firstCommand | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1,$2}' | xargs -n2 sh -c 'secondCommand "$1" --second "$2"' _
```

Comment: You might consider a placeholder for `$0` to make the arguments `$1` and `$2` (and to prevent `$0` from being used in error messages from the shell), but I'm very happy to see this answered in a way that doesn't involve injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: (adding double quotes as in `sh -c 'secondCommand "$0" --second "$1"'` would also improve correctness)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, ok, added improvements

Comment: @Emel, you're welcome. Use the updated version

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Just a small correction, the right spelling will be `xargs -n2 sh -c 'secondCommand "$0" --second "$1"' _`

Comment: @Emel, no, read the the 1st comment

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry! Lost that